# How to change figsize keeping imshow aspect='equal'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, figsize

Is there a way to change the figsize of a matplotlib figure *after* drawing an image with `ax.imshow()`?

I have a numpy array of size `(10, 100)` (let's say) and I want to plot it with `ax.imshow()`. It should look like the code below, more or less:

```
some_image = np.random.rand(10, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

ax.imshow(some_image)
```

and I get this:

[My output with lots of blank space above and below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFz5p.png)

What I'd like to do is to change the figsize of my `fig` object accordingly to my `ax.imshow` output, so that I have less blank space above and below but I need to keep `imshow(aspect='equal')` as I am plotting an image.

**I am not asking to remove the blank space entirely** (as I found in some questions), because I need the axes and the labels, only to reduce its size.

I already read different answers on here, but everyone was only answering to set `aspect='auto'` in `imshow`, to fit the image to the figsize. I need to do the other way around.

I also tried `plt.tight_layout` as suggested in another answer (I'll update the link if I find it again) but with no success.